# Postman or Insomnia 'No body returned for response', what does this mean?

Tags: postman, insomnia

I have a stored procedure which returns a result set when run in SSMS, but when I try to run the equivalent GET call in Postman or Insomnia  'No body returned for response' is the error. I can't see any difference in my set up comparing to calls I can get to work, can someone please explain what this error is suggesting?

Comment: That is not an error. The HTTP protocol allows not having any content in the "body" but just Headers response. What do you have in your response headers?

Answer (score 0):

So eventually sussed that I had to specify '.xml' in the call
https://some.website.com/SomeService/SomeData/TestProc.xml?param=1234

Not entirely clear why this call works differently from every other call I use that work without specifying 'xml', but at least now it works.